# Generate CEP event if found same data 5 times within 5 second in Apache flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-cep

I have a requirement to generate CEP event if we found string message starts with character '**a**' continuously **5** times within **5** second.

For that i have written a class **CEPCharEventPublisher.java** which will publish the string message (as below **Published message**) to kafka topic '**charEvent**'

**Published message:**

```
b; date- 2019-06-27 09:05:09.605
a; date- 2019-06-27 09:05:10.160
c; date- 2019-06-27 09:05:10.661
b; date- 2019-06-27 09:05:11.162
c; date- 2019-06-27 09:05:11.669
b; date- 2019-06-27 09:05:12.175
b; date- 2019-06-27 09:05:12.675
b; date- 2019-06-27 09:05:13.176
a; date- 2019-06-27 09:05:13.676
c; date- 2019-06-27 09:05:14.176
b; date- 2019-06-27 09:05:14.677
b; date- 2019-06-27 09:05:15.177
b; date- 2019-06-27 09:05:15.678
c; date- 2019-06-27 09:05:16.178
a; date- 2019-06-27 09:05:16.679
c; date- 2019-06-27 09:05:17.179
c; date- 2019-06-27 09:05:17.680
c; date- 2019-06-27 09:05:18.180
c; date- 2019-06-27 09:05:18.681
c; date- 2019-06-27 09:05:19.181
c; date- 2019-06-27 09:05:19.681
a; date- 2019-06-27 09:05:20.182
c; date- 2019-06-27 09:05:20.682
b; date- 2019-06-27 09:05:21.182
c; date- 2019-06-27 09:05:21.682
b; date- 2019-06-27 09:05:22.183
a; date- 2019-06-27 09:05:22.683
b; date- 2019-06-27 09:05:23.184
a; date- 2019-06-27 09:05:23.684
c; date- 2019-06-27 09:05:24.184
b; date- 2019-06-27 09:05:24.685
b; date- 2019-06-27 09:05:25.186
c; date- 2019-06-27 09:05:25.687
b; date- 2019-06-27 09:05:26.187
a; date- 2019-06-27 09:05:26.687
a; date- 2019-06-27 09:05:27.188
a; date- 2019-06-27 09:05:27.688
b; date- 2019-06-27 09:05:28.188
b; date- 2019-06-27 09:05:28.688
```

Now I have a consumer **CEPCharEventConsumer.java** which will read message from Kafka topic **charEvent** and filter the message which starts with character '**a**'.

Then I have written following pattern to generate CEP event/alert while we found the continuously **5** message, that starts with character '**a**' within **5** second.

```
Pattern<String, String> pattern = Pattern.<String> begin("start")
                .times(5).greedy().where(new SimpleCondition<String>() {
                    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6301755149429716724L;

                    @Override
                    public boolean filter(String value) throws Exception {
                        return value.split(";")[0].equals("a");
                    }
                }).within(Time.seconds(5));
```

Printing the message that starts with character 'a' received by **CEPCharEventConsumer.java** in below.

```
2> a; date- 2019-06-27 09:05:10.160
1> a; date- 2019-06-27 09:05:13.676
3> a; date- 2019-06-27 09:05:16.679
2> a; date- 2019-06-27 09:05:20.182
3> a; date- 2019-06-27 09:05:22.683
1> a; date- 2019-06-27 09:05:23.684
3> a; date- 2019-06-27 09:05:26.687
1> a; date- 2019-06-27 09:05:27.188
1> a; date- 2019-06-27 09:05:27.688
1> a; date- 2019-06-27 09:05:29.198
2> a; date- 2019-06-27 09:05:30.199

1> a; date- 2019-06-27 09:05:33.703
1> a; date- 2019-06-27 09:05:35.203
3> a; date- 2019-06-27 09:05:36.705
2> a; date- 2019-06-27 09:05:38.207
1> a; date- 2019-06-27 09:05:39.709
2> a; date- 2019-06-27 09:05:40.209
3> a; date- 2019-06-27 09:05:40.728
```

Printed alert message:

```
4> Found: a; date- 2019-06-27 09:05:26.687
```

In the above message "**Found: a; date- 2019-06-27 09:05:26.687**" is the alert message.

I could not understand how flink calculate the continuous five message within 5 second. I think something wrong is there.

I am attaching the [GIT URL](https://github.com/changeprasant/Flink-Apps/tree/master/flink-cep-char-event) of source code ([flink-cep-char-event](https://github.com/changeprasant/Flink-Apps/tree/master/flink-cep-char-event)). can anyone please make it correct as per my requirement.

Comment: What's the problem? I see 5 events from 09:05:26.687 to 09:05:30.199, which is less than 5 seconds.

Comment: David Anderson, I have separated the received message and alert event message. The message between 09:05:26.687 to 09:05:30.199 is received message, Its not event message. I will feel good if you ll check once my code in CEPCharEventConsumer.java

Comment: I still see 5 messages in a row within 5 seconds, starting with the message at 09:05:26.687.

Answer (score 1):

Your CEP-based application appears to be correctly reporting that these 5 messages

```
3> a; date- 2019-06-27 09:05:26.687
1> a; date- 2019-06-27 09:05:27.188
1> a; date- 2019-06-27 09:05:27.688
1> a; date- 2019-06-27 09:05:29.198
2> a; date- 2019-06-27 09:05:30.199
```

occurred within a 5 second interval.

The `processMatch` method in your `PatternProcessFunction` is passed a  `Map<String, List<String>> match`. In your case `match.get("start")` returns a list of the 5 matching events in the "start" clause of your pattern (which is the entire pattern).

So to produce a report that gives the time of the last matching event, rather than the first one, change

```
String start = match.get("start").get(0);
out.collect("Found: " + start);
```

to

```
String last = match.get("start").get(4);
out.collect("Found: " + last);
```

Comment: Thanks David Anderson for your confirmation, Now i understood. Can flink CEP  generate event on message 09:05:30.199 instead of 09:05:26.687 by reading 5 message from 09:05:26.687 in above list? if possible please let me know how?